# get value from json response in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am new to php. I trying to get value from json object.
I tried many time but i failed to get value from json. I need only "txnToken" from json array.
My code is

```
$json = json_decode($data, true);
foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
           print_r($key1);
           
    }
}
```

And JSON Response is:

```
{
    "head": {
        "responseTimestamp":"1596640639585",
        "version":"v1",
        "clientId":"WEB",
        "signature":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "body":{
        "resultInfo":{
            "resultStatus":"S",
            "resultCode":"0000",
            "resultMsg":"Success"
        },
        "txnToken":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "isPromoCodeValid":false,
        "authenticated":false
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `json["body"]["txnToken"]` and read **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)**

Comment: Look at the data in a sensible fashion and it becomes almost simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it should be as easy as this:

```
$json = json_decode($data, true);
print_r($json['body']['txnToken']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if you do

```php
$json['body']['txnToken']
```